# How many integers 1 to 1000 are multiples of 3 or 9?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I'm stumped about how to solve this, because every multiple of 9 is already a multiple of 3.

Here's what I have so far:

A = 999/3 = 333
B = 999/9 = 111

(A ∩ B) = multiples of 9 from 1 to 1,000, which equals 111

(A ∪ B) = A + B − (A ∩ B)
= 333 + 111 − 111
= 333

Comment: 333 is correct.

Comment: $B$ is subset of $A$ so $|A \cup B| = |A|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a solid application of the inclusion/exclusion principle. You do have the correct answer.
Is your apprehension as to how the inclusion/exclusion principle works in particular situations?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, exactly. I haven't used the inclusion/exclusion principle quite like this before. Because an integer can't be a multiple of 9 without being a multiple of 3

Comment: The calculation for the A ∩ B is floor division of your target number by the least common multiple of 3 and 9. Which is why 1000/9 works.

Comment: As others have stated inclusion/exclusion more relevant when the factors are different. Say 6 and 10... I say this because if you're taking this in a discrete cs course the prof might want to have you specifically use inc/exc over other more efficient methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply ignore the "or multiples of $9$" for the very reason you state. Inclusion exclusion plays no part. That shows up when you first add and then subtract $111$.

If the question asked about "multiples of $3$ or multiples of $5$" your argument would be necessary.